# How to use assertRaises from testpack in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, exception

I am learning Haskell and I want to do TDD.
I am trying to test if a function raise an expected exception.
I am using HUnit and [testpack](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/testpack).

testpack provides an assertRaises function but I don't manage to compile my code :(

Here is my source code :

```
module Main where
import Test.HUnit
import Test.HUnit.Tools
import Control.Exception

foo n   | n > 2 = throw ( IndexOutOfBounds ( "Index out of bounds : " ++ ( show n ) ) )
foo n | otherwise = n

testException = TestCase( assertRaises "throw exception" ( IndexOutOfBounds "Index out of bounds : 4" ) ( foo 4 ) )

main = runTestTT ( TestList [ testException ] )
```

When I compile it with ghc I get the following error message :

```
test_exceptions.hs:10:107:
    No instance for (Ord (IO a0))
      arising from a use of `foo'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Ord (IO a0))
    In the third argument of `assertRaises', namely `(foo 4)'
    In the first argument of `TestCase', namely
      `(assertRaises
          "throw exception"
          (IndexOutOfBounds "Index out of bounds : 4")
          (foo 4))'
    In the expression:
      TestCase
        (assertRaises
           "throw exception"
           (IndexOutOfBounds "Index out of bounds : 4")
           (foo 4))

test_exceptions.hs:10:111:
    No instance for (Num (IO a0))
      arising from the literal `4'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num (IO a0))
    In the first argument of `foo', namely `4'
    In the third argument of `assertRaises', namely `(foo 4)'
    In the first argument of `TestCase', namely
      `(assertRaises
          "throw exception"
          (IndexOutOfBounds "Index out of bounds : 4")
          (foo 4))'
```

What's wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`assertRaises` expects its third argument to be an IO action (with type `IO a`), but the return type from `foo` is a number (with type `(Num a, Ord a) => a`), not an IO action.

Try replacing `(foo 4)` with `(evaluate (foo 4))`.

Comment: I don't think `return` will work here due to laziness. `evaluate` should do the job, though.

Comment: @hammar How sloppy of me. Thanks.